# Microsoft Word 2003 - Debug loading times?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, latency

Loading new and most local documents is fast as hell,
but a few specific documents can take up to 10 minutes to load, which is not acceptable.

I know that these documents have macros enabled and active, also they appear to use some network traffic but routing the requested hostnames to 127.0.0.1 didn't really help.

I'm working on a LAN with the server the document is trying to look up is not available.

Is there any way to debug exactly what's happening inside the document at opening time, parameters or 3:d party applications? Perhaps I can modify the macro to not spam and delay due to network connections if that's the issue.

Comment: For the slow loading documents what does word's splash screen say when you double click to open?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be very similar to this question - [Word documents very slow to open over network, but fine when opened locally - on one machine](https://superuser.com/q/361193/97028), but not an exact duplicate, IMO. Maybe those answers can help you though.

I would like to say this, broken links to external data/documents will cause huge delays. For each link, Word waits a set amount of time for it to timeout. Multiply that by the number of broken links and you will need a Snickers bar because you are going to be there a while.

To remove all hyperlinks in a document, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire document and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.